# WPF TreeView - Apply styling based on enum value

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, treeview

I have a `TreeView` bound to an `ObservableCollection` containing `enum` values:

```
public enum Categories
{
    CatA, CatB, CatC, CatD
}

public ObservableCollection<Categories> CategoriesList = new ObservableCollection<Categories>();

foreach (Categories cat in (Categories[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Categories)))
{
    CategoriesList.Add(cat);
}
```

The `TreeView` is bound to `CategoriesList`:

```
tvCat.ItemsSource = CategoriesList;
```

The the XAML markup:

```
<TreeView x:Name="tvCat">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                 <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                 </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

I am trying to figure out how to apply individual stying to `TreeViewItem` for each enum value, e.g. blue color for `CatA`, red color for `CatB`, may be an icon for `CatC` etc.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Check out this: [C# – Enum Color Converter with IValueConverter](https://code.4noobz.net/c-enum-color-converter-ivalueconverter/)

Comment: Did you try using DataTriggers?

Comment: @Suresh I am not sure how to target a particular `enum` value with `DataTriggers`. Most examples show how to work with a `Property` of a `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataTrigger`s to get the desired output.

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </Trigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="CatA">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="CatB">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

**EDIT**

The above XAML is if you just want a different color for your Items. If you also want to have different content (e.g. an icon for CatC), then you'd have to set the `ControlTemplate` based on a `DataTrigger`.

Here is the XAML to achieve that.

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem" x:Key="CatCTemplate">
        <Image Source="icon.jpeg" Height="64" Width="64" />
    </ControlTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </Trigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="CatA">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="CatB">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="CatC">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CatCTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```